# Fast way to find elements in list of hashed tuples in python

Tags: python, sorting, hash, hashmap, bisect

I am trying to solve the following problem efficiently:

Given the following class

```py
class Obj:
    t1: int
    t2: int

    def __hash__(self):
        # compute hash on frozenset to make sure switching the to and from id has no effect
        return hash(frozenset((self.t1, self.t2)))

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Obj'):
        pairs = (self.t1, self.t2)
        return other.r1 in pairs and other.t2 in pairs
```

Hence, `Obj(t1=1, t2=2) == Obj(t1=2, t2=1)`

So given a set of `Obj` as in `s = {Obj(1, 2), Obj(1, 3), Obj(4, 1), Obj(9, 5)}` how can I find all objects which have either `t1=1` OR `t2=1`? So from from the set above I only would get `[Obj(1, 2), Obj(1, 3), Obj(4, 1)]`

What I have tried so far:
My current approach is to sort the set twice. Once with `s_t1 = sorted(s, lambda x: x.t1)` and `s_t2 = sorted(s, lambda x: x.t2)`.

I used `sortedcontainers` for convenience but one could also use classical `bisect`

```py
key = 1
from sortedcontainers import SortedKeyList
s_t1 = SortedKeyList(s, key=lambda x: x.t1)
s_t2 = SortedKeyList(s, key=lambda x: x.t2)

t1_results = s_t1[s_t1.bisect_key_left(key):s_t1.bisect_key_right(key)]
t2_results = s_t2[s_t2.bisect_key_left(key):s_t2.bisect_key_right(key)]
output = t1_restuls + t2_results
```

However, this feels inefficient since I need to sort twice.
Hence I am wondering what would be a better and faster (!) approach to do this. In particular, how can I make better use of the fact that `Obj(t1=1, t2=2) == Obj(t1=2, t2=1)` when searching the list?

Comment: `[obj for obj in s if obj.t1 == 1 or obj.t2 == 2]`???

Comment: Wait wait wait. Why is `Obj(4, 1)` included in your expected output? It has *neither `t1==1` nor `t2 == 2`*....

Comment: It seems like you *actually* want `keys = (1,2); [obj for obj in s if obj.t1 in keys or obj.t2 in keys]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh so sorry my mistake. I meant t1==1 OR t2==1 I corrected it. And yes I could go through the whole list, but I shouldn't need to do this if I have sorted it.

Comment: But *sorting it goes through the whole list*. So you aren't avoiding anything by sorting.

Comment: its a one time upfront cost. After that, each additional search can be done much more efficient.